# Change MediaWiki root location

Tags: ubuntu, mediawiki

I installed MediaWiki on Ubuntu 14 and the site has URL: www.wiki.example.com/mediawiki/

However I want to change to location to www.wiki.example.com/

I already modified LocalSettings.php `$wgScriptPath = "/mediawiki";` to `$wgScriptPath = "/"` but when the site loads, it becomes `http://index.php/Main_Page`

What should I do?

Update: I created symbolic link from `/var/lib/mediawiki/*` to `/var/www/html/` and changed Apache config to look for index.php first in dir.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this configuration in `LocalSettings.php`:

```
$wgScriptPath = "";
$wgArticlePath = "/$1";
$wgUsePathInfo = true;
```

Comment: I got this error `Call to undefined function wfShorthandToInteger() in /var/lib/mediawiki/includes/Setup.php on line 303`